# Creating responsive div on text content with no Bootstrap

Tags: css

I am trying to create responsive div with image, text and spacing between divs.
I had divs with spacing and text but they wouldn't resize on more text.
I am trying to achive something like this.
[image]

This one is with more text in some of the divs and every other div resizes as well.
[image]

Here is what i got:

```css
.img{
 width:300px;
 height:100%;
}
.image { 

   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h3{
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

   position: absolute; 
   top: 105px;
   left: 0; 
   width: 300px; 
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>sadasdsadsadsadsadsadasdasdsadsadsadsadas</h2>

</div>
```

i need div to resize to amount of text and covers bottom part of it.
Currently i am breaking text with < br >   which is not how i am aiming to do it.

Comment: Have you tried using word break? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you'd like to have hyphenation, you could use the css "hyphens" property, which lets the browser decide where to break. See an example (with fallback, as the browser [support is not so good, especially for some languages](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens))

```css
h3 {
     word-break: break-word; /* non standard for webkit */ 
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
}


.img{
 width:300px;
 height:100%;
}
.image { 

   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h3{
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

   position: absolute; 
   top: 105px;
   left: 0; 
   width: 100px; 
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3 lang="en">A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3 lang="en">A Movie in the Park: Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3 lang="en">Incomprehensibilities </h2>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how could it be done so the "area" for text stretches to the bottom of the image even when it is not 2 lines long?

Comment: I really need that stretching on the text when it changes :/

Comment: @AESTHETICS Use `bottom:0` instead of `top:115px`. This way the text will always be at the bottom, independent of its height (which depends on the amount of lines)

Comment: I got it to work like this but for some reason had to change it to  bottom:-15px; but i am really happy about the output. Do you know why i had to change it to -15px to make it line up? https://jsfiddle.net/2jbjz9p0/

Comment: + Is there a way to push text a bit from the border of the box so it is not so close?

Comment: @AESTHETICS use `padding` to push the text from the border, set the image to `display: block` and the `h3 { margin: 0; }` if you want to get rid of the bottom: 15px.

Comment: Can you create  a snippet please? I am not sure how to follow some of the steps.

Comment: Okay, so i made it like this https://jsfiddle.net/2jbjz9p0/1/  I am curious about  margin in h3 and display: block

Answer (score 2):

Try `word-wrap: break-word;` property on `h3`

```
h3{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Hope this Helps..

Answer (score 0):

`sadasdsadsadsadsadsadasdasdsadsadsadsadas` this is garbage value, this is not word you can use like this

```css
.img{
 width:300px;
 height:100%;
}
.image { 

   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h3{
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

   position: absolute; 
   top: 105px;
   left: 0; 
   width: 300px; 
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>sadasdsa dsadsadsadsa dasdasdsads adsadsadas</h2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `word-break: break-all;` to `h3`

```css
.img{
 width:300px;
 height:100%;
}
.image { 

   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h3{
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   word-break: break-all;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 105px;
   left: 0; 
   width: 300px; 
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png" alt="" class="img" />
      
      <h3>sadasdsadsadsadsadsadasdasdsadsadsadsadas</h2>

</div>
```